# FORCE_SSL_ADMIN not working

Tags: wp-admin, security, wp-login-form, ssl

Any ideas why `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` wouldn't work?

I'm not getting any errors at all, but a `http` request to `example.com/wp-admin` isn't redirecting to `https`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured it out... It was the positioning of the define statement.

I added the below above the `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */` line

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
```

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else reading this answer `FORCE_SSL_LOGIN` is depreciated since 4.4.0.

Comment: When giving notices of deprecation like this, please include a description of what should be done instead, if anything.

Comment: The answer is not very helpful since there is no clear reason *why* this helps. Also, you didn't mention FORCE_SSL_LOGIN in your question. Did you also add that, or was it already there?

Comment: @ijt Use just `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` as described [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/administration-over-ssl/). Internally [force_ssl_login](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/force_ssl_login/) delegates the call to [force_ssl_admin](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/force_ssl_admin/).

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if WordPress is hosted behind a reverse proxy that provides SSL.

Paste the following in your theme's functions.php:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
// a comma-separated list e.g. http,https
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would even go as far as setting up .htaccess to rewrite the request to https for a specific folder, aka /wp-admin/
For example

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin/$1 [R,L]
```

Also it looks like `FORCE_SSL_LOGIN` was depreciated since 4.0, so in your answer you would only need `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` which should take care of LOGIN and ADMIN areas.

More on [Administration Over SSL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/administration-over-ssl/)